# Process names 0, 1, 2

Tags: linux, process, manjaro, gnu, htop

I see 0, 1, 2 and 3s in htop. I can't kill these (sig 9). They are sometimes consuming a bit of my cpu for a second. I wonder what they are... Killall just says process not found if I try to kill them as root and kill with the pid does nothing.

I'm using Manjaro.

I'm assuming that they are kernel related because htop shows them in green but I really wonder for what they are.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are seeing in _htop_. Is it a process ID? Or the process name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're kernel threads. But those are not the actual names – this is htop's failed attempt at showing the "basename" of the process name. For example, for normal daemons like `/usr/bin/sshd`, htop trims it down to just `sshd`.

But what you're seeing here are not daemons but kernel threads, with actual names like `ksoftirqd/0` or `cpuhp/1`, which htop trims incorrectly. So first press <kbd>p</kbd> to see the full name, then try to determine the purpose from that.

(Also press <kbd>t</kbd> to enable tree view so that all kernel threads will be grouped under `kthreadd`.)

For example, `ksoftirqd/[0123]` is explained at https://askubuntu.com/questions/7858/why-is-ksoftirqd-0-process-using-all-of-my-cpu and https://man.cx/ksoftirqd(9).

Overall it's normal for kernel threads to occassionally use some CPU, because *that is why they exist*. If a kernel thread had absolutely nothing to do, ever, then it wouldn't have needed to be created.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to disable trimming for kernel processes/threads?